# adding libs ONCE for lifetime in autocad 2012

Tags: autocad, autodesk-inventor

I am using Autocad 2012. I need to upload libs everytime when I open the Autocad. Is there any way how to avoid this and load libs file by-default when Autocad 2012 is opened?

Please let me know what needs to be done.

Note : some libs are there by-default.